# Java Parameter specified as non-null is null IllegalException method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics

Tags: java, android, firebase

This question has been asked already but it doesn't have an answer and i'm looking for help in this.
I want to integrate stripe to my android firebase app.But I keep getting the error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull. I am not using kotlin in my project but java so I'm not sure where kotlin comes from.

Error

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.myapp.app, PID: 26686
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter clientSecret
> at com.stripe.android.model.ConfirmPaymentIntentParams$Companion.createWithPaymentMethodCreateParams(Unknown Source:29)
> at com.stripe.android.model.ConfirmPaymentIntentParams$Companion.createWithPaymentMethodCreateParams$default(ConfirmPaymentIntentParams.kt:420)
> at com.stripe.android.model.ConfirmPaymentIntentParams.createWithPaymentMethodCreateParams(Unknown Source:14)
> at com.myapp.app.PaymentPageActivity.lambda$startCheckout$0$PaymentPageActivity(PaymentPageActivity.java:84)
> at com.myapp.app.-$$Lambda$PaymentPageActivity$lysPf2qYJjjVdPRqihuLblLplpI.onClick(Unknown Source:2)

```
  //My code 
    
     // Configure the SDK with your Stripe publishable key so it can make requests to Stripe
        stripe = new Stripe(
                getApplicationContext(),
                Objects.requireNonNull("stripe_key")
        );
        startCheckout();
    }
    private void startCheckout() {
        // ...

        // Hook up the pay button to the card widget and stripe instance
        Button payButton = findViewById(R.id.payButton);
        payButton.setOnClickListener((View view) -> {
            CardInputWidget cardInputWidget = findViewById(R.id.cardInputWidget);
            PaymentMethodCreateParams params = cardInputWidget.getPaymentMethodCreateParams();
            if (params != null) {
                ConfirmPaymentIntentParams confirmParams = ConfirmPaymentIntentParams
                        .createWithPaymentMethodCreateParams(params, paymentIntentClientSecret);
                confirmParams.getPaymentMethodCreateParams();
                final Context context = getApplicationContext();
                stripe = new Stripe(
                        context,
                        PaymentConfiguration.getInstance(context).getPublishableKey()
                );
                stripe.confirmPayment(this, confirmParams);
            }
        });
    }

    // ...

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Handle the result of stripe.confirmPayment
        stripe.onPaymentResult(requestCode, data, new PaymentResultCallback(PaymentPageActivity.this));
    }

    // ...

    private final class PaymentResultCallback
            implements ApiResultCallback<PaymentIntentResult> {
        @NonNull private final WeakReference<PaymentPageActivity> activityRef;

        PaymentResultCallback(@NonNull PaymentPageActivity activity) {
            activityRef = new WeakReference<>(activity);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(@NonNull PaymentIntentResult result) {
            final PaymentPageActivity activity = activityRef.get();
            if (activity == null) {
                return;
            }

            PaymentIntent paymentIntent = result.getIntent();
            PaymentIntent.Status status = paymentIntent.getStatus();
            if (status == PaymentIntent.Status.Succeeded) {
                // Payment completed successfully
                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
                Toast.makeText(PaymentPageActivity.this, "Paymen success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else if (status == PaymentIntent.Status.RequiresPaymentMethod) {
                // Payment failed
                Toast.makeText(PaymentPageActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull Exception e) {
            final PaymentPageActivity activity = activityRef.get();
            if (activity == null) {
                return;
            }

            // Payment request failed – allow retrying using the same payment method

            Toast.makeText(PaymentPageActivity.this, "Error " +e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }
```

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace and code

Comment: @Fabio I just edited my question. Please tell me you can help me.

Comment: It seems you are not initializing `paymentIntentClientSecret` before this line `ConfirmPaymentIntentParams confirmParams = ConfirmPaymentIntentParams
                        .createWithPaymentMethodCreateParams(params, paymentIntentClientSecret);`. It must have a non-null value.

Comment: I was this documentation it did'nt say  anything about that. How should I initialize it?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#android-create-payment-intent), you should request a PaymentIntent from your server in order to get your client secret. There's [a full example on GitHub](https://github.com/stripe-samples/accept-a-card-payment/blob/dd18f67b7d1a26a7fd4dd2d8f02457d5531a01f4/using-webhooks/client/android/app/src/main/java/com/example/app/CheckoutActivityKotlin.kt#L73) that may help you.